# SQL Server PIVOT functionality

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, unpivot

If we `PIVOT` any table and `UNPIVOT` that table do we get our original table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, will not always get the same table as the original table. It depends on the kind of data that we are looking at.

Check the SQL Fiddles for @Mahmoud Gamal 's data.

[SQL Fiddle With SUM](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/77dcd4/2)

[SQL Fiddle With MAX](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/77dcd4/1)

Comment: Please downvoter care to explain, what is the problem in this answer?????????????

Answer (score 0):

No you can get different result. because use aggregate function in pivote. and when you unpivote pivoted query maybe get different result, that such as aggregated orginal table on pivote fields.